# wso2 api manager path pattern issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm having issue with what I feel is a simple url pattern match, but seeing unexpected behavior for an API I created.

I set up the API, and when I place the "URL Pattern", I do something simple like "/player/{playerId}"

When I go to the next screen to input the endpoint information, I reference my path variable as it appears in the documentation, like `http://mycoolendpoint.com/playerInfo/{uri.var.playerId}`

What I end up seeing is that the entire URL pattern is being appended to my endpoint.  So, in the above, instead of seeing the expected `http://mycoolendpoint.com/playerInfo/111`, I see coming across the wire `http://mycoolendpoint.com/playerInfo/111/player/111`

Am I setting up something wrong when I do this syntax that it's appending the entire URL pattern to the Sandbox and Production endpoints instead of just the value of the path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API's resource is normally appended to its endpoint URL by API Manager by default So to avoid this you can follow below instructions,

1. Create a custom sequence with the following content and save it as a .xml file.

```xml
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestSequence">
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

2. Now edit your API in publisher. In design view go to "Message Mediation Policies" section and Enable Message mediation. Now add a In Flow and upload the previously saved sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this by defining your API like below.

1) Define resource like this.

```
playerInfo/{playerId}
```

and define endpoint like this.

```
http://mycoolendpoint.com/
```

Or

2) Define resource like this.

```
/{playerId}
```

and define endpoint like this.

```
http://mycoolendpoint.com/playerInfo/
```

Or you can also do this as @ycr has mentioned. If you want to do that change for all APIs without creating a custom sequence file, you can add below line inside [InSequence section](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/master/modules/distribution/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml#L298) of  `<APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml` file.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

This template is used when APIM creates synapse files of new APIs.